# Zoom without changing Camera center

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

I have a `GMSMapView` which is centred around User's GPS location.

When the user double taps, the map's centre shifts to the touched location, instead I just want the map to zoom without changing the Camera location!

Went through the docs, unable to figure out how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the answer myself by digging into their source code as its not mentioned anywhere in the docs!

This particular behaviour(zoom without changing camera centre) is a config item called, `allowScrollGesturesDuringRotateOrZoom` (who would've guessed!) in GMSUISettings class, so you can access it on your `GMSMapView` object's 'settings' property like below,

Obj-C:

```
mapView.settings.allowScrollGesturesDuringRotateOrZoom = NO;
```

Swift 2.1:

```
mapView.settings.allowScrollGesturesDuringRotateOrZoom = false
```

Now on zoom (double tap / pinch), the scroll won't happen, effectively keeping the camera view unchanged!

Comment: Great stuff! Were there any side effects though ?

Comment: Nope, no side effects! Works perfectly fine.